# How to import Neural Networks from ONNX?

Tags: import, neural-networks

ONNX is a open format to represent deep learning models.

So I want to import neural networks from other frameworks via ONNX.

[image: import workflow]

And the `Mathematica 11.3` supports python now.

I think I can use [ONNX-MXNet](https://github.com/onnx/onnx-mxnet) to export the `mxnet.json` and `mxnet.params` then just `Import` these.

But I have no idea about how to install packages on Python-ExternalSessions.

---

### Example

Here is an [onnx-format file](https://s3.amazonaws.com/onnx-mxnet/examples/super_resolution.onnx) of Super Resolution Model.

How can I import this using Mathematica and Python-ExternalSessions?

Comment: According to this live CEOing video, it looks like it's in the works. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l_KzSb9GGbE

Comment: According to [this](https://www.zdnet.com/article/wolfram-research-goes-for-software-2-0-releases-neural-net-repository/) article, it will be possible in Mathematica 12.

Answer (score 7):

This is incomplete answer because Mathematica doesn't support the latest version of mxnet.

**Step 1**

Install `onnx-mxnet`. Open Command Prompt and enter:

```
pip install onnx-mxnet
```

[image]

**Step 2**

Download [model](https://s3.amazonaws.com/onnx-mxnet/examples/super_resolution.onnx) and [image](https://s3.amazonaws.com/onnx-mxnet/examples/super_res_input.jpg). Run this code in Mathematica:

[image]

```
import mxnet as mx
import onnx_mxnet
import numpy as np

sym, params = onnx_mxnet.import_model('C:/Users/Alexey/Documents/super_resolution.onnx')

from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('C:/Users/Alexey/Documents/super_res_input.jpg').resize((224, 224))
img_ycbcr = img.convert("YCbCr")
img_y, img_cb, img_cr = img_ycbcr.split()
test_image = np.array(img_y)[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :, :]

mod = mx.mod.Module(symbol=sym, data_names=['input_0'], context=mx.cpu(), label_names=None)
mod.bind(for_training=False, data_shapes=[('input_0',test_image.shape)], label_shapes=None)
mod.set_params(arg_params=params, aux_params=params, allow_missing=True, allow_extra=True)

mod.save_checkpoint("super_resolution",1)


net = Import["super_resolution-symbol.json", "MXNet"]
```